# Piwik - Setting up with Oracle DB instead of mysql

Tags: database, oracle, rhel, matomo

I can't go forward with my Piwik configuration. Is it possible to set up PIWIK with an Oracle DB at the moment? I'm searching for the answer since last monday, but no success until today.

- Piwik 3.0.4
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.0
- rhel 7

I would be thankful for any help.

Best regards,
Burak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment piwik supports only MySQL

Source: https://piwik.org/faq/how-to-install/faq_55/